# Multidimensional array in Scala

Tags: java, arrays, scala

Is it possible to create a multidimensional array in scala without using the "Array()"

Like this in java:

```
int[][] myIntArray = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it without `Array()`?

Comment: Its a bit cleaner and like it that way... (This is more like a yes / no question)

Comment: Try to provide a type alias for Array to simplify the notation. Thats what you want?

Comment: More or less yes... (Seems a bit overkill for an array of 16 Integers)

Comment: Or probably not... (See answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you dont want to declare the array repeating `Array` a lot of times.

You can try this:

```
val > = Array

val x: Array[Array[Int]] = >(
  >(1, 2, 3),
  >(4, 5, 6),
  >(7, 8, 9)
)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862568/initializing-a-2d-multi-dimensional-array-in-scala)  (There are other suggestions also)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. I just couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Hi JosEdu, out of curiosity I'm asking this, Can't we declare the above example like this, ` val > = Array; val x: >[>[Int]] = >(
  >(1, 2, 3),
  >(4, 5, 6),
  >(7, 8, 9)
)`